# Cosa significa questo? se si può preghiamo di rispondere in inglese sarebbe molto apprezzato

Tags: translation, meaning

To seguo ricambi? 
Cosa significa questo? Mi è stato chiesto questa domanda su un altro sito sociale, ma non so cosa voglia dire per favore mi aiuti

Comment: Just to let you know, it's perfectly fine to ask a question in English here, so if by any chance you have some trouble with the language you can ask your questions directly in English from now on; also feel free to [edit your question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/posts/5747/edit) and to rephrase it in English if that happens to be easier for you.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I presume the question was "Ti seguo, ricambi?" (missing comma added because the question looks appalling without it), and I assume it was asked on Twitter or on some social network of some sort where users can follow each others.

Basically the user is stating that he followed you and he's asking you if you're willing to follow him in exchange.

- "Ti seguo": "I'm following you"
- "ricambi?": "will you do the same [in exchange]?"